# Basic OCaml OOP question

Tags: oop, ocaml

I am attempting to learn oCaml and am having an issue as to why the below program is invalid.

```
class myClass2 =
object
 method doSomething = Printf.printf "%s\n" "Doing something"
end;;

class myClass foo =
object
 val dMember = foo
 method doIt = dMember#doSomething
end;;

let mc2 = new myClass2;;
let mc = new myClass mc2;;
mc#doIt;;
```

The error I receive when trying to compile the program is:

```
File "sample.ml", line 6, characters 5-84:
Some type variables are unbound in this type:
  class myClass :
    (< doSomething : 'b; .. > as 'a) ->
    object val dMember : 'a method doIt : 'b end
The method doIt has type 'a where 'a is unbound
```

I am particularly interested as to why:

```
val dMember = foo
method doIt = dMember#doSomething
```

is invalid. Any (and I mean *any*) help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the type:

```
class myClass (foo:myClass2) =
```

Comment: Wouldn't that defeat the purpose of using structural typing in the myClass.doIt method?

Comment: Note that this isn't necessary. Rather you could write `class myClass (foo : <doSomething : unit; ..>) = ...`

Answer (score 6):

OCaml objects can't have free type variables in their signatures. Since the type of the  argument `foo` is not fully specified, you need to parameterize `myClass` by the free variables in the type of `foo`.

```
class ['a] myClass foo =
object
 val dMember = foo
 method doIt : 'a = dMember#doSomething
end;;
```

This definition has the type

```
class ['a] myClass :
  (< doSomething : 'a; .. > as 'b) ->
  object val dMember : 'b method doIt : 'a end
```

This is similar to normal parameterized dataypes, e.g., `'a tree` (the brackets around the `'a` are just a bit of syntactic cruft). Note that `'a` is the type of `foo#doSomething`, not of `foo`.

```
# let x = new myClass (new myClass2);; 
val x : unit myClass = <obj>
# x#doIt ;;
Doing something
- : unit = ()
```